# My Jquery does not connect to my html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my jquery is not connecting and I cannot figure out why. I've been stumped on this for hours and I cannot figure it out.

this is my html code. The file name is exercise6.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
    
<head>

    <title>Exercise 6</title> 
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/exercise6.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>

      <form id="email_form" name="email_form" action="exercise6.html" method="get">
     <fieldset class="info">
     <legend>Contact Information</legend>
     <p>
       <input type="text" name="Lname" id="name2" value="" required />
    <label for="name2"> Last</label>
     </p>
     <p>
       <input type="text" name="mailAddie" id="mail1" value="" required />
    <label for="mail1"> Address</label>
     </p>
      <p>
       <input type="text" name="City" id="city1" value="" />
    <label for="city1"> City</label>
     </p>
      <p>
       <input type="text" name="State" id="state1" value="" />
    <label for="state1"> State</label>
     </p>
      <p>
       <input type="number" name="Zip" id="zip1" value="" />
    <label for="zip1"> Zip</label>
     </p>
      <p>
       <input type="number" name="phoneNum" id="number"  />
    <label for="number"> Phone</label>
     </p>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
     <legend>Sign up for our email list</legend>
       <p>
       <label for="email_address1"> Email Address</label>
       <input type="text" name="email_address1" id="email_address1" value="" />
    <span>*</span><br>
    </p>
    <p>
       <label for="email_address2"> Confirm Email Address</label>
       <input type="text" name="email_address2" id="email_address2" value="" />
    <span>*</span><br>
    </p>

    <p>
       <label for="first_name"> First</label>
       <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="" />
    <span>*</span><br>
     </p>

  </fieldset>

  <p>
     <label>&nbsp;</label>
     <input type="submit" value="Join Our List" id="join_list" > 
        </p>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is my javascript. The file name is exercise6.js and it is located in a file named JS. I do not know what I am doing wrong.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#join_list").click(function() {
  var emailAddress1 = $("#email_address1").val();
  var emailAddress2 = $("#email_address2").val();
  var isValid = true;
  
  if (emailAddress1 == "") {
   $("#email_address1").next().text("This field is required.");
   isValid = false;
  } else {
   $("#email_address1").next().text("");
  }
  if (emailAddress2 == "") {
   $("#email_address2").next().text("This field is required.");
   isValid = false;
  } else {
   $("#email_address2").next().text("");
  }
  if ($("#first_name").val() == "") {
   $("#first_name").next().text("This field is required.");
   isValid = false
  } else {
   $("#first_name").next().text("");
  }
  if (isValid) {
   $("#email_form").submit();
  }

 )};
)};
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking the browser's debug console for errors?

Comment: At which path is the html file located?

Comment: Open the console to see the errors. You have `)};` instead of `});`.

Comment: Try to load the scripts at the end of the page, right before de `</body>`

Comment: Your reference to js file ( JS/exercise6.js) would only work if your html file resides at the same location as JS folder.

Comment: Isn't your `submit` button reloading the whole page ???? try adding a `preventDefault()` on the click function

Answer (score 1):

The last two lines of exercise6.js both have a syntax error.

Change:

```
    )};
)};
```

To:

```
    });
});
```

To find this yourself next time, try using web development IDE like NetBeans with the help of right click with mouse to inspect in browser debug console, which would have even shown you where is this kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Your js code has some errors for close the function "});"  try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#join_list").click(function() {
        var emailAddress1 = $("#email_address1").val();
        var emailAddress2 = $("#email_address2").val();
        var isValid = true;

        if (emailAddress1 == "") {
            $("#email_address1").next().text("This field is required.");
            isValid = false;
        } else {
            $("#email_address1").next().text("");
        }
        if (emailAddress2 == "") {
            $("#email_address2").next().text("This field is required.");
            isValid = false;
        } else {
            $("#email_address2").next().text("");
        }
        if ($("#first_name").val() == "") {
            $("#first_name").next().text("This field is required.");
            isValid = false
        } else {
            $("#first_name").next().text("");
        }
        if (isValid) {
            $("#email_form").submit();
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: I fixed the errors but nothing. I think it has something to do with my html but I don't know

Comment: is working for me I assume is the  location path  it should to be folder->exercise6.html and JS(folder)->exercise6.js(inside JS folder). The image is in the answer